# Plink и .bat - параметры открывающегося окна

Tags: bat, putty

Запускаю через bat файл несколько сессий plink. Текст батника:
`start plink.exe -telnet 192.168.254.10
 start plink.exe -telnet 192.168.254.20
 start plink.exe -telnet 192.168.254.30`
Все сессии открываются, но заголовок окна plink показывает путь до plink.exe (E:\PuTTY\plink.exe)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Возможно ли изменить эту надпись на свою при помощи бат файла?
Спасибо.

Comment: `START /?` много чего рассказывает. Обратите внимание на самый первый параметр, который в кавычках...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Желаемое имя окна можно указать первым параметром команды start

```
start "DEV1" plink.exe -telnet 192.168.254.10
```